# WebBrowser as Canvas Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I like to add a WebBrowser control as a Canvas background in WPF using C#. How do I do this? I have the following code at the moment. But does not work.

```
<Canvas
  Name="canvas"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
  Grid.Row="1"
  MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
  MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
  MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
  Margin="0,0,0,16"
  Grid.RowSpan="3">
  <Canvas.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <WebBrowser
          x:Name="wbMain"
          Height="246"
          Width="592" />
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The web browser control is an Internet Explorer ActiveX wrapper with the resulting airspace issues.

However, you can draw on top of it using the `<Popup>` control or if you don't mind losing the interactivity, try generating an image of the web page and use it as the Canvas background.

If you are thinking about using the [WPF Chrome wrapper by Chris Cavanagh](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/a-real-net-4-0-webbrowser/), bear in mind:

- It does not yet support COM-Visible (so no `window.external` javascript methods back to your C# code)
- It has a dependency on [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/licensing/) which is only free for non-commercial use.
- It will add over 10MB to your code size as it needs to embed Chromium

Comment: Note the above answer is really old, and I think they have solved this in WPF now.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control isn't a standard WPF control as far as I'm aware. It's basically an embedded window with an IE control in it. I'm fairly certain you can't use it in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's an embedded IE window, so you can't use it that way.

You CAN, however, use the chrome one that way: http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/

You can also map it to a surface, animate it etc.

Comment: can this thing also call C# methods from javascript and javascript methods from c#?